# How is Pseudomonas aeruginosa diagnosed?

Tags: microbiology, medicine

I know that *P. aeruginosa* is cultured on an agar plate, but which media or assays make it distinct from other Gram-negative bacteria?

Comment: Welcome to SE BIology. Please take the time to take the Tour and find out about this site. After that, the Help on asking questions should be your next call.  You need to show that you have done some research for yourself first before posting here. Tell us where you have searched an dwhat you have or have not found.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is actually a Wikipedia search away. But from the 7th edition of the book *Microbiología Médica* and [Todar's Online book of Bacteriology](http://textbookofbacteriology.net/pseudomonas.html):

- **Nutriotional needs**. Simple. Part of why *Pseudomonas* spp. grows everywhere is that it can metabolize a wide array of carbon and nitrogen-containing compounds. Blood agar and McConkey are enough for its growth.
- **Colonies**. They generally show a mucoid appearence and are flat.
- **Respiration**. Practically an obligate aerobe. Usually oxidizes glucose, but it is capable of anaerobic respiration as well, using nitrates or arginine as electron donors. The **cytochrome oxidase** assay is **positive**, unlike Enterobacteriaceae and *Stenotrophomonas*.
- **Pigmentation**. *P. aeruginosa* synthesizes pyoverdin (fluorescent and green) and pyocyanin (blue and water-soluble). Pyocyanin is produced when the presence of iron in the media is low, however, and not all strains synthesize it.
- **Temperature**. Its optimal temperature is 37ºC, but its survival range is quite wide, from as low as 4ºC to as high as 42ºC.
- **Antibiotic resistance**. And to many antibiotics. The presence of beta-lactamases makes *P. aeruginosa* withstand penicillin, carbapenems and cephalosporins.
- **Odor**. Cultures emit a pleasant aroma that most associate with grapes or soap.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomonas_aeruginosa#Identification) does show a nice battery of tests that identify *P. aeruginosa*, but if I were you I would compare them to other sources.

- **Positive**: oxidase, citrate, motility, gelatin hydrolysis, acid production (from glucose and mannitol), nitrate reduction, lipase, pigmentation (green or blue), catalase and beta-hemolysis.
- **Negative**: Gram staining, indole production, methyl red staining, Voges-Proskaeur (?), hydrogen sulfide production, urea hydrolysis, phenylalanine deaminase, lysine decarboxylase, acid production (from lactose, maltose and sucrose) and DNAse.